# Does anybody knows how to save variables in file for each sampler in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm sending websocket requests(json) and get some responses from server.
Than I'm saving in variables some parameters' values from derived response(using Regular Expression Extractor). 
How can I save values of this variables in file for each sampler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) after Regular Expression Extractor.
2. Put the following code into PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   String sampleName = prev.getSampleLabel();
   String var = vars.get("myVar");
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(sampleName + ".txt"), vars.get("myVar"));
   ```

Where:

- `prev` - stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `vars` - [JMEterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) instance for current thread group
- `FileUtils` - [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class instance

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.